# Python count list's values and put them in ordered list without library

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list

```
List = ['Antonia', 'Sara', 'Nick', 'Deppy', 'Antonia', 'Deppy', 'Antonia']
```

And I want to count all of them

Nick: 1

Sara: 1

Deppy: 2

Antonia: 3

Is there a way to make a new list which they are ordered like this:

```
New_List = ['Antonia', 'Deppy', 'Sara', 'Nick']
```

?

Comment: Your list isn't valid Python.

Comment: You can use count()

Comment: Well,I have not found a way to do it with count(). ///
If I understood corectly, the count() counts only a specific value or am I wrong?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: I think that this uses Counter library,but I am not allowed to use a library

Comment: You're not allowed to use the standard library?

Comment: No. It's a project which does not let me use libs

Comment: for now I have found this which does not help much: ///
New_list = {x:list.count(x) for x in list}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your goal. Here is a simple way to do:

```
the_list = ['Antonia', 'Sara', 'Nick', 'Deppy', 'Antonia', 'Deppy', 'Antonia']

# count unique item in the list 'the_list'
for item in set(the_list):
    print(item, ':', the_list.count(item))

# an ordered new list containing unique item of 'the_list'
new_list = sorted([item for item in set(the_list)])
print(new_list)
```

> **Outputs:**

```
Nick : 1
Antonia : 3
Sara : 1
Deppy : 2

['Antonia', 'Deppy', 'Nick', 'Sara']
```

Comment: The first part is correct,but the new_list is not very correct...

Comment: `Nick`comes before `Sara` because the list is *alphabetically* sorted. You make a mistake in your post. Go check it.

Comment: Yeah,I meatn he who has the biggest number will be first,then the next one etc.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Please, make your point more clear!

Comment: Let's say I have Antonia 5 times and Nikos 3 times. ///
So I want the first one to be he who is written most of the times.
So Antonia > Nikos. As a result the list has first Antonia and then Nikos.
If Nikos was written 6 times, then Nikos > Antonia. As a result first in the new_list would be Nikos and then Antonia.